# jquery ajax request not starting - no errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to repair a simple form which should be sending a simple email

I receive no javascript errors, but the ajax request is not fired. I seached a lot of answers here and in google, but none was helping my case.

Here the form html code

```
<form method="post" id="signupform">    
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nimi"><br>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="sähköposti@osoite.com"><br>
<p><a href="#" id="send"><b>Ilmoittaudu</b></a></p>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

And this is the jquery validation and sending code:

```
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "13 october 2013 12:00:00", <!--set website launch date and time here-->
        format: "on"
        },
        function() {
            // callback function
        });
    var left = $('.newsletter').offset().left;
    $("#subscribe").click(function(event){
        $(".newsletter").show().animate({ left : left }, { duration: 1000 });
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;               
    });
    $(".close1").click(function(event){
        $(".newsletter").animate({ left : "110%" }, { duration: 1000 });
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;               
    });
    $("#send").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var cname = $("#signupform").find("#name").val();
        var cemail = $("#signupform").find("#email").val();
        var errcount=0;
        if(cname.length < 1) {      
            $(this).parent().find("#name").addClass("error");
            errcount = 1;
        } else
           $(this).parent().find("#name").removeClass("error");
        var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$/i);
        var valid = emailRegex.test(cemail);
        if (!valid) {
            $(this).parent().find("#email").addClass("error");
            errcount = 1;
        } else
            $(this).parent().find("#email").removeClass("error");
        if (errcount === 0 ) {
            alert('noerror');
            //form submitted succesfully
            $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'send.php',
                data: {
                    name: cname,
                    email: cemail
                },
                processData: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    alert('success');
                    if (response == 'Kaavake ei ole täytetty oikein') {
                        $('#response').html(response);  
                    } else {
                        $('#response').html(response);
                        $('#response').fadeIn('slow');                  
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, text, error) {
                    alert(text);
                    alert(error);
                }                   
            });            
        } else {          
            return false;
        }
    }); 
    $("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({deeplinking:false});
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var height=$('.activeslide').height();
        var sidebarheight=$('.sidebar').height();
        $('.sidebar').css('min-height',height);
    }); 
    $(window).resize();
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

The alert with noerrors is shown, but not the alert with success, and I cannot see the ajax activity in the network of chrome dev-tools.

Here the code from send.php

```
<?php

$subject = "Uusi ilmoittautuminen";
$error = 0;
$sendto = 'email@yahoo.com';
print_r($_POST);
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //validate and strip user data
    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $name =  htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
    } else { 
        $error = 1; 
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $email =  htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    } else { 
        $error = 1; 
    }   
    if ($error == 0) {
        //SENDING SECTION
        //prepare body
        $namesender = 'Yhteydenotto';
        $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n".
            "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n".
            "From:Yhteydenotto < noreply@mail.com >\r\n" .
            "Reply-To:".$name." <".$email.">\r\n".
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $body = "Uusi ilmoittautuminen\n\nNimi: ".$name."\n\nSähköposti: ".$email."";
        //prepare subject
        $newsubject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';

        //send email
        $mailresult = mail($sendto, $newsubject, $body, $header);

        die("<p>Kiitos ilmoittautumisestasi!</p>");

    } else {
        echo 'Kaavake ei ole täytetty oikein';
        die;
    }

} else { echo 'no direct access allowed'; }
```

Comment: Is any error logged in console? Check if serialize method is returning the desired params correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I did an `alert(params);` after the var params but the alert box was not shown?? strange, the noerror alert worked.. I get no error codes in dev-tools

Comment: Are you sure the element exists before you try to put the handler on the object (e.g. is this in an onload or `$(document).ready( );`?

Comment: @Owl Then the problem was with serialize method :). Your ajax code seems correct.

Comment: @Sumurai8 yes the document ready is there, thanks

Comment: @Moniecorleone thank you so much! How can I debug this? The documentation to the serialize method does not say anything about debugging, and I do not receive any error?

Comment: Add TRY CATCH block and check if any exceptions is occurring. Else, instead of serialize object retrieve the values directly using Jquery selector and pass them as params.

Comment: I think $.ajax might fail silently if you don't specify a function for 'error' (much like 'success'). Try adding the following to the settings array:

`error: function( x, y, z ) { console.log( x ); console.log( y ); console.log( z ); }`

Comment: @Moniecorleone did you mean this kind of catch block like in bottom of edited question (from luk32302s answer)

Comment: @Sumurai8 thanks I added the error check from the previous answer, still no change

Comment: No i meant this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: @Owl show us your `send.php`, cause the ajax request working fine as i tested http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/CrQdT/

Comment: Can you post your send.php code???

Comment: @Moniecorleone I edited the question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what does the `return false;` do after the success method? better remove that. furthermore you have semicolon after the `url: 'send.php';`it should be a normal comma.
Except that everything looks right.

For finding this kind of errors just check the console (i think) every browser enables you to use. There warnings and errors are logged.

http://jsfiddle.net/EvXgZ/2/ there you have working version with just the addition that i had dto change the destination url to work on jsfiddle.

your ajax call should look like

```
$.ajax ({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'send.php',
  data: {
    'name': cname,
    'email': cemail
  },
  async: false,
  success: function(response) {
    alert('success');
    if (response == 'Kaavake ei ole täytetty oikein') {
      $('#response').html(response);  
    } else {
      $('#response').html(response);
      $('#response').fadeIn('slow');                  
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, text, error) {
    alert(text);
    alert(error);
  }
});
```

As a matter of fact this version works and all the confusion resulted of a `//` in front of the pasted code, which was additionally pasted in one line and therefore was never excuted. One more important thing to note is that if you develop and change your js-files, you always have to make sure that they are cleared from the cache so you really load the latest version on the website if you visit and test it

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the semicolon with comma and removed the return false, no change :(

Comment: i added an error handler to tell you whats wrong if it is still not working.

Comment: thank you so much, I edited my question and added the improved code. With this code I receive the no error alert but nothing happends after that...

Comment: @Owl _nothing happends after that_ means no success message??

Comment: @luk2302 yes sorry this is getting difficult so many people answering (thanks anyway) I edited the question with the whole javascript in the newest version

Comment: no still not. This is driving me nuts! I have emptied the cache and tried it again with the code from the question. After the no-error alert I no not receive any response from the site

Comment: can you give me a link to the site you are developing on? maybe there is something different than in the pure jsfiddle setup!?

Comment: @Owl and what params you are sending through form?

Comment: that is of no interest, as unimportant as what send.php looks like.

Comment: @jogesh_pi The params are just simple typing asdfasdf and asfasdf@asdfasdf.de as its a name and email

Comment: @Owl everything seems to working fine as i tested in my local.

Comment: @jogesh_pi thanks this is driving me nuts I included in the comment above the real url

Comment: remove the comment in front of the ajax. you currently dont execute the ajax.

Comment: I CANNOT BELIEVE THIS!!!! This is some kind of serious nerve wracking code.. I downloaded the whole script from server and it had thrown me the complete ajax request behind the comment and of course uncommented it. How can this happen? Now its working more than before... I need serious vacation

Comment: so it works? as far as i could see something with the php is wrong to, but the js itself works?

Comment: yes the js is workin now, I am getting the post printed from the send.php.. I have never experienced before that somehow the server changes the source code.. Or was there some bogus char in the sourcecode? I am working with notepad++, so this cannot happen?

Comment: somehow the code you pasted in your source was in one single line and therefore the `//` commented everything. i personally use an more complex ide than notepad++ -> netbeans :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32333/discussion-between-luk2302-and-owl)

Answer (score 0):

add

```
     $("#send").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   //ajax code    
     })
```

Comment: Thank you, I did and tried again with emptied cache.. No change

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error

```
$("#send").click(function() {
    var cname = $("#signupform").find("#name").val();
    var cemail = $("#signupform").find("#email").val();
    var errcount = 0;
    if (cname.length < 1) {
        $(this).parent().find("#name").addClass("error");
        errcount = 1;
    } else
        $(this).parent().find("#name").removeClass("error");
    var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$/i);
    var valid = emailRegex.test(cemail);
    if (!valid) {
        $(this).parent().find("#email").addClass("error");
        errcount = 1;
    } else
        $(this).parent().find("#email").removeClass("error");

    if (errcount === 0) {
        alert('noerror');
        // form submitted succesfully
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : 'send.php',
            data : {
                name : cname,
                email : cemail
            }, //Missing , here
            processData : false,
            async : false,
            success : function(response) {
                alert('success');
                if (response == 'Kaavake ei ole täytetty oikein') {
                    $('#response').html(response);
                } else {
                    $('#response').html(response);
                    $('#response').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            },
            error : function(xhr, text, error) {
                alert(text);
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you I added the missing comma, still no change, but thanks anyway